# Install or import in Python?

Tags: import

I am a beginner in Python, trying to still learn the basics. I am mostly interested in using it for Data Analysis and Visualizations, with packages such as matplotlib.

Most of the examples I see, use the code

"import matplotlib"

or something similar.

But there are also cases when people suggest using pip install the use the package.

So, as a rule of thumb, when should one use import and when should one install through the terminal?

Comment: There is no thumb rule for using a method to install. You can use any method for installing. Aim is to install so that the library is available when the code is interpreted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you want to use some library. Let its name be `ABC`. ABC has some function, let's say `function1`.
If you write

```
import ABC
ABC.function1()
```

you will get error. Because in your virtual environment python can't find library called ABC. You must install it first using `pip install ABC` in your terminal. After that same code will work.
You must install library first in order to use it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no thumb rule for using a method to install. You can use any method for installing. Aim is to install so that the library is available when you run the code, else you will get an error.

In Windows, if you want to install a package/library use the following Command on DOS Prompt

`python3 -m pip install matplotlib`.

To Upgrade the same, use the following Command on DOS Prompt

`python3 -m pip install --upgrade matplotlib`.

You can install and upgrade the package/libraries through **Jupyter** too.
Once installed, you need to place the `import <library_name>` on top of the code in which you want to use that library.